# how to solve a revolutionary body by two line segments with same length

Tags: math, line

There are two ray lines,
which can be denoted as

Line A: P1=p10+n1*t

and

Line B: P2=p20+n2*t

where, p10 and p20 are the starting points of the two ray lines respectively.

I want to find a revolutionary body around an axis,
by which, 
the point p10 can be rotated to point p20 and the vector direction n1 can be rotated to vector n2.

The following is my thinking.

Assuming the unknowns of the revolution are its rotating axis (nx,ny,nz) and one point on  the axis x0,y0,z0.

Without loss of generality, z0 can be set to 0.
Because nx,ny,nz is a unit vector, the nz=sqrt(nx^2+ny^2).
And the rotating angle is theta.

So there are only five unknowns:  x0,y0,nx,ny,theta

The equations we can achieve are:

P1x=P2x

P1y=P2y

P1z=P2z

n1x=n2x

n1y=n2y

(As the n1 and n2 are unit vectors,so the relations n1z=n2z will be satisfied naturally)

So I think it should have a unique solution. But I am not sure. 
Also, if there is a solution, I don't know how to solve the equations.
It seems very difficult.

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you mean by revolutionary body, then I think there will be **many solutions** for any given input, unless the directions `n1` and `n2` are parallel to each other.

The base of any such revolutionary body will always be a circle passing through both points `P10` and `P20` and as you know there could be **many circles** that can satisfy this condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If  only two points are needed to rotate, it is correct that there are many solutions.  But the problem is that I also want to make the two direction vector also same.  I wonder if there is a solution.

Comment: @JilongYin If it helped you, Could you please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give me more ideas on this?

Comment: @JilongYin please post the question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) for more detail answers. Thanks.